# Start Activity and Show dialogbox at same time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I need to start inbuilt activity using intent (for eg. select permission for APP access) and in its main screen display dialog to guide user to check checkbox.
I implemented it following way

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dialog1 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme);
        dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.popup_window);
        dialog1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x80827871));
        dialog1.show();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_name");
            startActivity(intent1);
```

However, dialog goes in background. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: display dialog from onCreate of the 2nd activity...

Comment: That would definitely work. But, I can not access 2nd activity

Comment: With `Handler.postDelayed` you could schedule your dialog to be shown after that second activity is loaded. Might work?

Comment: so you are navigating the user to device settings page..?

Comment: yes. device setting. Where user needs to tick checkbox to allow App access. Clean master app has such dialog. So, I was wondering how did they do that